# Is AutoLayout mandatory for new apps using Xcode 6 iOS8?

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6

I am thinking to build next app without AL(AutoLayout). Still I can't get the logic of this "best" thing in iOS for PORTRAIT apps.  I am sure for both orientations is a magic tool, but I think everything can be applied simple for Portrait apps, for all devices, without AL. What do you think ?

1) Is AL mandatory for new apps in Xcode 6 and iOS8 ?

2) It is ok to use AL only for Landscape and Portrait Apps ?  As I see in almost all code examples where is AL, app is for both orientations.

3) If I will create new app, for iPhone, without AL, will AppStore reject my app?

Thanks you guys for any details about my questions!

Thanks

Comment: **Can anyone help here?  Thanks**

Comment: 1) No 2) it’s Ok, you can use whatever you want 3) No

Comment: @TonyMkenu Thanks so much!
PS: you from RO ?

Comment: For nothing.. and Yes :)